# Convergence of two sequences to the same limit

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_n$ be a sequence converging to $x$. And let $y_k$ be an *increasing* sequence converging to $x$. Is $$\sup x_n\geq  y_k \;\;;\;\;\forall k\geq 0 \text{ ? }$$

Comment: What does $\lim x_n = x$ tell you about $\sup x_n$?

Answer (score 3):

Since $\{y_n\}$ is increasing, $$\forall n.\;y_n \le x\le \sup \{x_n\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} x_n \geq x$, clearly (by contradiction, otherwise there exists an interval $I=(x-\alpha, \infty)$ with $\alpha > 0$ such that $\{x_n\}_n\cap I=\emptyset$, and $(x_n)_n$ cannot converge to $x$).

But it is the case that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $y_k \leq x$ (by assumption, since the series is increasing).

Comment: Nice one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sup x_n\ge \limsup x_n=x$ (Since $x_n$ converges to $x$) and $y_n\uparrow x\Rightarrow y_n\le x\forall n\ge 1$ Hnce $\sup x_n\ge y_k\forall k\ge 1$

Comment: Right. Thanks :)